# Click event before value change. (Checkbox)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

Using CheckBox and need to pop up a dialog BEFORE the check is set or unset.    What listener should I use?  Is there a previous value stored somewhere?

V/w
Wayne

Answer (score 1):

There is a variety of listeners on the `CheckBox` component.

If you use addValueChangeListener you'll get a `ComponentValueChangeEvent`
On this event, you can get the old value.

API:
https://vaadin.com/api/platform/23.0.0.alpha1/com/vaadin/flow/component/checkbox/Checkbox.html

Comment: My edit queue is full but here is the link that matches the tagged version (not that this particular feature has changed anyway): https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.8.1/com/vaadin/flow/component/checkbox/Checkbox.html